# Nuxt-Express Deploying to Azure Issue

Tags: node.js, express, azure-web-app-service, iisnode, nuxt.js

I am trying to get a nuxt with express web app deployed to an Azure Web App running Node.  Here's what I have done so far:

1. Created a build using VSTS
2. Deployed build to Azure Web App using VSTS release (using MS's Azure App Service Deploy task)
3. I also made a few changes per a couple closed issues:

   - Changed scripts to use fully qualified paths like "node ./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt start" based on response in this [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/733)
   - Created a stub server.js per response in this [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/465) but I did have to make a change to the call to nuxt.Server to be nuxt.listen(port, host) instead.
4. Enabled logging to the iisnode log folder based on this [iisnode.yml](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/iisnode.yml) file used in azure
5. Here is the log information being returned now that makes me think it is still a configuration issue:

   ```
   Sat Aug 26 2017 16:12:45 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
       at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
       at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
       at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
       at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
       at require (module.js:375:17)
       at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
       at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
       at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
   ```

Here are the contents of the **server.js** file I created based on the notes in 3:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt');
const resolve = require('path').resolve;  

const rootDir = resolve('.');
const nuxtConfigFile = resolve(rootDir, 'nuxt.config.js');  

let options = {};
if (fs.existsSync(nuxtConfigFile)) {
  options = require(nuxtConfigFile);
}
if (typeof options.rootDir !== 'string') {
  options.rootDir = rootDir;
}
options.dev = false; // Force production mode (no webpack middleware called)  

const nuxt = new Nuxt(options);  

const port = process.env.PORT;
const host = process.env.HOST;  

nuxt.listen(port, host);
```

If need be I can give you the **web.config** and **iisnode.yml** files if those would be helpful when looking at the config of the azure web app.

---

Also I have posted this as an issue in the nuxt.js github repo if you would rather answer this question [over there](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1489)

Comment: Have you checked out @shaydoc's [demo repo](https://github.com/shaydoc/nuxtexpress) in GitHub, or did you have any other problems?

Comment: Yes, Shaydoc's demo helped quite a bit.  I will post my solution to this question tomorrow (if work allows).  Good news is I got it working!